# Xpages OneUI 3.02 paging looks terrible; how to replace with OneUI 2

Tags: xpages, ibm-oneui

I prefer OneUI V3.0.2 to 2.0 except for one element, which is paging. I think the new style looks horrible.

Here is an example of the old paging style:

[image]

And here is an example of the new styling:

[image]

I would like to replace the new styling with the old, but just for this one element, or at least to create my own style for paging.

I have looked at the OneUI documentation, but there is something that I don't understand. I am using a dataView in my layout, but when I go to look at how things are implemented, it always seems that they are using raw html, so there is a table element in there. I don't understand that. I want to know how to style a custom control, not html.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Styling is done by your browsers rendering engine. It applies CSS to HTML. That's how it works. So you need to create some CSS with !important to fix it.
Easiest way to figure it out: load the page, use FF or Chrome Dev tools that allow you to live edit the CSS and see the result instantly. Once you have it, copy to a CSS file and add to your project.

Comparing to a V2 page makes it easier to figure out.

Just reading the CSS source is rather a pain. The Dev tools rock

Comment: Stephen, I understand that the CSS is applied to the HTML. I have been doing what you recommend, using Safari or Chrome's web tools. However,  I code in Xpages. Why can't IMB also show XML code that generates the HTML/CSS? Why do I have to figure reverse engineer everything. I know that a dataView or repeat generates a table, and styles are applied to that table. But what XML generates the examples on the oneUI documentation page. Am I missing something?

Comment: I wanted to add, I am looking at the nextGen theme. I think that looks nicer and might fix several of the aesthetic issues I have.

Comment: The sequence is XML -> Java source -> compile -> HTML. The oneUI documentation is completely INDEPENDENT from the XPages environment and NOT coded in XPages, but manually in HTML (it is used in other environments too). So there is no XML that generated it